# Will Firefox OS support OpenCL, or even WebCL?

Tags: firefox, webgl, opencl, firefox-os

Does anybody know if Firefox OS will support OpenCL and also WebCL out of the box ?

If not, will it be likely to support both in the future?

Comment: Please leave a comment,when voting down my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely it won't.

Given the current roadmap of FXOS releases, there is much to come but no OpenCL implementation is on the way.

If you want to find out what is coming on the next releases, take a look at our [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Roadmap)

There is also plenty of information available on the [B2G Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G)

I'm just a mozilla volunteer, but if you still want to have your question taken beyond, please fell free to open a bug at [our bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Also, please feel free to join our irc (irc.mozilla.org) and visit the following rooms for more info #b2g, #firefoxos, #gaia, there might be people available to have a chat with you.

Hope I could at least give you some guidance.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Firefox/Firefox OS will not support WebCL.  There is little (no?) mobile support of OpenCL, and not much developer interest even on desktop.  Having Firefox OS support WebCL/OpenCL through untested drivers, with developers unlikely to target it given lack of support elsewhere, doesn't make much sense.

Instead, we will focus on ARB_compute_shader as an extension for WebGL, given its presence in ES3.1 and in desktop OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

The opencl is an standard. Thus the firefox may implement an internal opencl. This permite the opencl code may run at any platform, since the developer of the code within of one site  can put a "if then else" saying "if  is not exist  opencl implementation of manufactures of the device  then use the firefox implementation". I do belive  that the  webcl standard should  charge  this. Because this isn't hard of make.
Already exist one implementation  open source of opencl the http://portablecl.org/